# Xamarin C# - is using navigation page or ListView in the TabbedPage

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, navigation, tabbedpage

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKZyZ.jpg)

refer to the above image. It is a TabbedPage with 4 tab page. May I know how can we perform this action. When user click the list, it will navigate to a new page (outside of the tabbedpage). Then, it can go back to the TabbedPage when back button clicked.
 Is it using ListView or navigation page? 
Please advise. thank you.

Comment: I already go through the docs microsoft. It didn't help my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.create a Tabbed Page and set it as mainPage of app.**

[image]

> in App.xaml.cs

```
public App()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyTabbedPage());
}
```

**2.Put the contentPage in the Tabbed Page which contain the listview.**

For example ,I put the listview in MainPage.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App8"
         x:Class="App8.MyTabbedPage">
<!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
  <ContentPage Title="Tab 1" Icon="xxx.png"/> //set the title and icon of toolbar item
  <local:MainPage Title="Tab 1" Icon="xxx.png"/>
  <ContentPage Title="Tab 1" Icon="xxx.png"/>
</TabbedPage>
```

> in MainPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App8"
         x:Class="App8.MainPage">

<ListView  x:Name="listView" ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell Height="30">
               ...
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

</ContentPage>
```

**3.When you click the item of listview navigate to a new contentPage which contain your other listview**

> in MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
  Navigation.PushAsync(new xxxContentPage(),true);
}
```

Comment: Hi, but how can i display the right arrow on each cell in my list view ?